# CSS page margin content not appearing

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS (started looking at it yesterday!) so this is probably a very simple problem and hopefully someone will be able to help.

I can't seem to get any text to appear in the margin boxes of a print-formatted page.

Below is a very basic HTML snippet that should put "There should be something here!" in the top-left margin box and "This is the body of the page..." in the main page area.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<STYLE type="text/css">

@page {
  @top-left{ 
  content: "There should be something here!"; 
  }
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 50;
}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<P>This is the body of the page...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The body text appears but the margin text does not.

My ultimate aim is to create automated test reports so I need to have identical headers and footers for multiple pages and will fill the main page area with the test data.

Thanks in advance,
Pete.

Comment: CSS is not correct. Please read how to use selectors and what is HTML.

Comment: Why do you have content in the style tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The generic recommendation for you would be to go through some html and [css tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/css/), [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com) (some methods and technics might be deprecated) or better to use official references alike [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) or [official W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/).

If you find this extremely tricky for you, and you still feel the need, you may use [HTML editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors) with WYSIWYG components, they will simplify the start for you.

Comment: Looks like I tried to run before I could walk - back to the tutorials then! Thanks.

Comment: @Wavemaster, down-vote just because of personal preference? you comment is not constructive. It was just the sample, to start with, these resources have their own drawbacks, but w3scrhools is better for newbies, IMHO. I personally referencing only [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) so down-vote was not really fair.

Comment: w3schools is not better for newbies. It teaches deprecated and sometime even dangerous code. It's not associated with w3c. If you referencing MDN, do it in your answer too.

Comment: @Wavemaster, thanks for the input, consider to re-vote, I extended the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`@top-left` is not supported from all engines.

See the anser on a simulare questions: [CSS Paged Media Contents Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996242/3504500)

Comment: I think you overthink it a bit... There was not a single mention on layout engines or features support.

Comment: @Farside Disagree, the question asked about getting content in a print-formatted page. For example, you might want page numbers in a particular format. From the question asked this answer is appropriate as it states the reason that PJOwen cannot see the page margin content.

Comment: @jonnow, it up to you disagree or not to agree. It is an off-topic to answer me here, under a different answer, which is not even mine. I'm happy that I helped to the original topic starter a long time ago, and he already said "thanks" in the comments.